# How to use json data that 'arrives' X seconds later?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm filling out a list with a json. However that json (php file) gives me the result X seconds later (unknown time).

External file - Getting the json data:

```
$(function(){
                // can't modify this file
                $.getJSON('json.php',
                    function(data) {            
                    items = [];
                    $.each(data, function(key, val) {
                            items.push('<li id="' + key + '">' + val + '</li>');
                    });
                });
    });
```

Inline code - Output:

```
<script>   
 $(function(){
                $('<ul/>', {
                        'class': 'my-new-list',
                        html: items.join('')
                }).appendTo('#result');
        });
</script>
```

Right now I see nothing in `#result` because both codes are being loaded at the same time so the output can't find the 'items'.

How could I modify the **Inline code** in order to force it to wait until the external file gives me the json data ? Maybe an observer ?

EDIT: It looks like I didn't explain it well enough. I'm sorry for my poor english. I'm also a Js/Jquery newbie.

EDIT 2: If we have no delay getting the json data everything works, however it depends on some external devices connected through serial communications and sometimes it takes 2,3 or 5 seconds to get the json.

Comment: It can't find `items` because this variable defined in another scope.

Comment: If you can't modify the first file, how do you expect to get the `items`? The timing seems irrelevant.

Comment: Thanks for your helpful comments. Unfortunately I'm (still) a newbie.

Comment: you could override $.getJSON with your own wrapper

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your only option is going to be to use a setInterval that periodically checks for the data to become available. The ideal way would require modifications to file 1.

```
function handleData(items) {
    // dostuff with items
}

var itemsInterval = setInterval(function(){
    if (items && items.length) {
        handleData(items);
        clearInterval(itemsInterval);
    }
},250);
```

Comment: I just edited the question to clarify because it works when there is no delay. Thanks!

Comment: @Shaz If your code works when the delay is small, that means file1 isn't like you posted it in your question. As it is now, what you are saying works isn't possible. `var items =` is probably just `items =`

Comment: Thanks for updating your answer. I appreciate it.